# module 'yaml' has no attribute 'FullLoader'

Tags: python

I am seeing the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generateLDA.py", line 14, in <module>
    config = yaml.load(fp, Loader = yaml.FullLoader)
AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'FullLoader'
```

Comment: add the full code and also please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add your Python version, yaml package you're using and that package's version.

Comment: python 3.6 in google colab I am using

Answer (score 119):

The `FullLoader` class is only available in PyYAML 5.1 and later. Version 5.1 was [released on March 13, 2019](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML#history) and has probably not filtered down to many distributions yet.

You can check the version of PyYAML by inspecting `yaml.__version__`:

```
Python 2.7.15 (default, Oct 15 2018, 15:24:06) 
[GCC 8.1.1 20180712 (Red Hat 8.1.1-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.__version__
'3.13'
```

If you are managing packages with `pip`, you can upgrade to the current release by running:

```
pip install -U PyYAML
```

Comment: Keep in mind that pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed for a given application. PyYAML is a popular dependency with other packages, and you might introduce new conflicts by upgrading.

Comment: true for e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)

Comment: I upgraded to 3.13, however, still there is no attribute yaml.FullLoader

Answer (score 12):

In case someone wants to use older version of yaml(3.1)

```py
import yaml
with open('filename.yaml') as parameters:
  my_dict = yaml.safe_load(parameters)
```

I stumbled upon it while using `rospy` to run my packages.

Comment: save_loader has another behaviour e.g. tuples will be loaded by FullLoader and won't by safe_load

Answer (score 8):

pip install --ignore-installed PyYAML

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo su
pip install --ignore-installed PyYAML -r requirements.txt
```

It worked perfectly for `fail2ban-geo-exporter`

Took hours to figure it out, now it runs under root & systemd

Comment: I would advise never to use pip/python as administrator as it may use different python binaries and/or different packages versions.

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install -U PyYAML

worked for me on Linux machine.

- if it was working earlier then please check whether the indentation of the file is somehow messed-up or not.

Comment: if pyyaml is already in your system then check once the alignment of of the file you are trying to parse.