# AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'FullLoader' - how to solve

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

My Code ist super simple.

```
import yaml
with open(r'C:\Users\data\insolvere.yaml') as file:
insolve = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

print(insolve)
```

I get the error mentioned in the title: `AttributeError: module 'yaml' has no attribute 'FullLoader'`

Comment: Your PyYAML version is probably too old. This was added in 5.1. But you can use `yaml.Loader` instead, it is an alias for FullLoader. If you don't need the capabilities of FullLoader, though, you should use SafeLoader.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [module 'yaml' has no attribute 'FullLoader'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551191/module-yaml-has-no-attribute-fullloader)

Comment: I had a similar problem. I replaced FullLoader with Loader and it worked